# Product of a digit with a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, product, multiplication

How do I get the product of a 1 number in bash? (12345 > 1x2x3x4x5)

I am trying to get a script to do multiplication, I have tried escaping the * char but no luck, I have also tried fiddling with expr.

```
echo -n "Enter number "
read n

len=$(echo $n | wc -c)

len=$(( $len - 1 ))

for (( i=1; i <= $len; i++ ))
do
   prod=$(($prod \* $(echo $n | cut -c $i) ))
done
echo "Product of $n is $prod"
```

Comment: The parsing rules change inside `$((...))`; you don't need to escape the `*`, because no pathname expansion is performed.

Comment: Thanks guys! I also managed to solve it through simplifying the for loop to  
    `prod=$((prod * $(echo $n | cut -c $i) ))` 
and setting a value to prod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the length of a string from parameter expansion, no need to call external tools.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Enter number: ' n

product=1
for (( i=0; i < ${#n}; ++i )) ; do
    d=${n:i:1}
    (( product *= d ))
done
printf '%d\n' $product
```

And, for fun, using Perl:

```
perl -MList::Util=product -le 'print product(split //, shift)' -- "$n"
```

Answer (score 1):

***gawk*** (GNU awk) solution:

```
echo 12345 | awk -v FPAT="[0-9]" '{ r=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) r=r*$i }END{ print r }'
```

The output:

```
120
```

---

- `FPAT="[0-9]"` - represents field value so that each field contains a digit

Comment: My mistake. Thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you want to get value of digits multiplication in number

Suppose you have number:

```
number=12345
```

You have to insert * between digits:

```
echo $number | sed 's/\([0-9]\)/\1*/g'
```

We will get string:

```
1*2*3*4*5*
```

We don't need last asteriks - let's remove it:

```
echo $number | sed 's/\([0-9]\)/\1*/g' | sed 's/.$//g'
```

We will get this:

```
1*2*3*4*5
```

We can now redirect it to calc:

```
echo $number | sed 's/\([0-9]\)/\1*/g' | sed 's/.$//g' | calc -p
```

It's stdout is:

```
120
```

Answer (score 1):

`\*` is wrong in an arithmetic expression, it should be `*` alone. But even then running your code gives:

```
$ bash product.sh
Enter number 12
product.sh: line 10: * 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* 1 ")
Product of 12 is
```

The reason for the error is that `$prod` variable is not set to an
initial value before so it's expanded to an empty value, for example
try it in your terminal:

```
$ echo $prod

$
```

In your script you should set `prod` to an initial value before using
it for the first time. It should be:

```
echo -n "Enter number "
read n

len=$(echo $n | wc -c)

len=$(( $len - 1 ))

prod=1

for (( i=1; i <= $len; i++ ))
do
    prod=$(($prod * $(echo $n | cut -c $i) ))
done
echo "Product of $n is $prod"
```

There are a few more problems with your code:

- always put a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top
- always [double quote](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) the variables
- using `$` on variables is not necessary in arithmetic expressions in `Bash`